# How to call a function in jQuery when Pop up is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using AjaxToolKit:ModelPopUpExtender to create a popup in asp.net application.
Initially the asp:Panel(Which contains the body of the popup) is set as

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanlUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" Style="display: none">
```

Now when the popup displays on the screen on a button click, is there a way in javascript or jQuery to know that the popup is displayed on the screen?

Actually when the popup displays it contains some text fields, and I want to get the value of those fields .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, looking for the `display` attribute in the style:

JS

```
if (document.getElementById('<%= PanlUpdate.ClientID %>').style.display === 'none')
{
    // The panel is not visible 
} 
else
{
    // The panel is visible
}
```

jQuery

```
if ($('#<%= PanlUpdate.ClientID %>').css('display') === 'none')
{
    // The panel is not visible 
} 
else
{
    // The panel is visible
}
```

Comment: when I put alert inside the if block it is running, but the else never runs. I have checked the css properties of the pop up when it is displayed on the screen- style="position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 173px; top: -2px;", I tried if($('#<%= PanlUpdate.ClientID %>').css('position')==='fixed') but it not showing any alert.

Comment: When the Panel is being shown write in the JS console $('#YourPanelGeneratedID').css('display') and see which is the value of the property